# prefabs are missing in unity3d project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am learning unity . I downloaded a project from version control ( and that app is live ) but I cannot build it locally ; its giving me missing prefabs ; tried everything that's available in unity forums still can't resolve. Any help would be greatly acknowledged. Thanks in advance .

p.s. The project is built using unity 5.4.2 and I am using 2018.4.17f1 (if that would help )

Comment: Missing prefabs usually indicate a reference error in regards to the project.
More information regarding the error message is needed to formulate an actual answer on what to do. The project could be missing some assets that have been depreciated in the unity version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In general avoid huge version jumps in Unity. Rather backup and upgrade a project in incremental steps and each time test between them! Between 5.4.2 (Okt 2016) and 2018.4.17LTS (Feb 2020) there passed over 3 years and a lot of things changed!

Especially the entire prefab system changed as there now are nested Prefabs etc. This might be the problem.

---

It is also very probable that a Unity git repository uses [`Git LFS`](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (large file storage).

In this case certain file types are not pushed into the repository itself but rather to the large file storage. In the git repository the files will then only contain references to where to download these large files.

You can try and

1. Download and install [`Git LFS`](https://git-lfs.github.com)
2. Open your `Git Bash` in the repository directory and run

   ```
   git lfs install
   ```

   This is needed once for each repository.
3. Download all LFS referenced files for a repository via

   ```
   git lfs fetch --all
   ```